# Where can I Implement a while loop in this code?

Tags: python

I am very new to coding so this question is probably very stupid and obvious, but where should I be putting my loops so that StuL does not reset every time I add a new key to the dictionary since so far every time I have tried to input loops the keys that have been added by the user keep resetting

```
import time
StuL = {"1317281" : "Name : Reese John ID :1317281 DoB : 12/11/95 Address 
: 57 Fake Road Phone Number : 02087475632 Gender : Male Tutor Group : 10K  
Email : JohnReese@HighSchool.com"} 
UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")
if UserName == "MrLeeman" and PassWord == "hunter2":
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Login successful")
    time.sleep(1)
    ch=(input("Enter your choice\n1:View student details\n2:Add 
    Students\n3:Exit"))
    if ch == "1":
        time.sleep(1)
        inp = input("Enter student's ID number")
        if inp in StuL:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(StuL[inp])
    elif ch == "2":
        time.sleep(1)
        edit=input("Enter the ID for the student you wish to add")
        inf=input("Enter the information for the student in the following 
        order\nName,ID,DoB,Address,Phone number,Gender,Tutor 
        Group,Email")
        StuL[edit] = inf
    elif ch == "3":
        break


   else:
        print("Invalid option")
else:
        print ("Password did not match")
```

Comment: Please don't link us to code images, copy your code with your favorite tool, and paste it here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: in addition to post code, not images of code, I find it difficult to guess what you are trying to do - please be more explicit. If you want a loop that modifies, but doesn't reset `StuL`, make sure you don't include the `StuL = {...}` in the loop body.

Comment: Please, in an actual program, do not ever waste the users time pretending to be doing something with a delay...

Comment: Wow thanks for the valid criticism  I understand why it was a stupid question but then again I am very new to programming and have only been doing python for a month or two

Answer (score 0):

I hope you learn something from this:

```
#!python3
#coding=utf-8

import sys
print(sys.version)

StuL = {
    "1": {
        "Name": "Reese John",
        "ID": "1317281",
        "DoB": "12/11/95",
        "Address": "57 Fake Road",
        "Phone Number": "02087475632",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Tutor Group": "10K",
        "Email": " JohnReese@HighSchool.com"
        }
}

UserName = input("Enter Username: ")
PassWord = input("Enter Password: ")
if UserName == "u" and PassWord == "p":
    print("Login successful")

    while(True):
        ch = input("Enter your choice\n1:View student details\n2:Add Students\n3:Exit\n")
        if ch == "1":
            inp = input("Enter student's ID number")
            if inp in StuL:
                print(StuL[inp])

        elif ch == "2":
            edit = input("Enter the ID for the student you wish to add")
            inf = input( "Enter the information for the student in the following order\nName,ID,DoB,Address,Phone number,Gender,Tutor Group,Email\n")
            StuL[edit] = inf
            # this does not create a Dictionary! Input needs to be parsed or separate.
        elif ch == "3":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid option")
else:
    print ("Password did not match")
```